# Firestore could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Error when starting React Native application with react-native run-android command

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, apk

I use firebase in my application. I always used expo start command and I am able to try application on expo app on the mobile emulator I use. I decided to generate an apk of it but it looks I couldn't. After running react-native run-android command, I can see the signin and signup screens but when I want to press a button that calls a function related to firebase firestore, application shows this error.

[image]

As I mentioned, I can use the application with all functionalities of it, functions related to firebase works well. How can I install the application on the emulator and use it as I use expo start ?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I tried the below answer by changing the rules but didn't work. Although mine is working fine on physical device but not working on android emulator. Can you help?

Comment: Unfortunately it has seemed it had worked but I guess I have runned the release one. I couldn't anything to do since then :/

Answer (score 0):

your problem maybe come from your firestore, you can change the ruels in firestore. for the steps:

1. open your firestore console
2. select your project
3. move to firestore database and click on Rules
4. try to change like this

   rules_version = '2';
   service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {
   match /{document=**} {
   allow read, write: if false;
   }
   }
   }

hope can solve your problem :)